# group by date clause giving different value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: user_transaction, transaction and users

I am trying to create a summary table of distinct transactions 
on a each date basis 
for each employee 
for each resource

as follows: (filtering datetime to date using format specifier)

```
select 
  count(distinct(user_transaction.trans_id)) as obj, 
  DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m-%d') as tdate
from 
  user_transaction, transaction,users 
where 
  users.id = user_transaction.user_id 
  and users.employeeid = 'samuel' 
  and user_transaction.trans_id=transaction.id  
  and resource_id =1 and transactiontext like '%<-->%' 
  and DATE_FORMAT(user_transaction.date,'%Y-%m-%d') 
    between '2011-08-30' and '2011-11-28'
  group by 
    DATE_FORMAT(user_transaction.DATE, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

result of the above query is I get distinct transaction count for user 'samuel' on each date in the range

e.g. 2011-08-30............22;
     2011-09-01............431;
     2011-09-03............64 ;
etc..

now I sum up all these values I get a count like total for the user : 1486

This count is not matching up with my modified query for the same user and date range if I do a direct count without the group by on Date field. 
i.e. If I run the query below without date grouping :

```
select 
  count(distinct(user_transaction.trans_id)) as obj, 
from 
  user_transaction, transaction,users 
where 
  users.id = user_transaction.user_id and users.employeeid = 'samuel' 
  and user_transaction.trans_id=transaction.id  
  and resource_id =1 and transactiontext like '%<-->%' 
  and DATE_FORMAT(user_transaction.date,'%Y-%m-%d') 
    between '2011-08-30' and '2011-11-28'
```

This gives me a count like 1452, 
the count over the range with date grouping and summing it to get total is generally more for every user, not sure why.

I need to have the counts calculated for each date for my summary table.

The count I get directly without using the group by clause is correct, checked it in the table.

What exactly am I doing wrong in the group by clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are counting the **distinct values** and grouping by date, it may be possible that you have the same trans_id on multiple days, thus giving you a greater count in the query with the group by than that without.

Comment: right now as i know it the trans_id i.e transaction id is a unique primary key, cannot be repeated on 2 different dates even for same user.

Comment: I assume that the primary key is actually transaction.id on the transaction table. Even if this is the primary key of the transaction table, that does not mean there are not duplicate matches in the user_transaction table or vice versa if my assumption is backwards.

Comment: It makes sense, Ideally every transaction recorded in the table needs to have a unique transaction id which is a foreign key in user_transaction table, but as you said if there are duplicates for trans_id for some reason in the table, then this inconsistency would arise. I will be reloading a sample of my production database to make sure the data is right and test this. Thanks for the help